# React MUI: table sort doesn't work with custom data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Good Day! Currently using Material-ui table, and I'm having an issue on sorting. I am trying to implement sort on a MUI table. But when I click on sort I con it doesn't sort the table data. Here is my code. I followed what's on the [documentation](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-table/) but sorting is not working on my side.

```
import React from "react";
import { lighten, makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Table from "@material-ui/core/Table";
import TableBody from "@material-ui/core/TableBody";
import TableCell from "@material-ui/core/TableCell";
import TableContainer from "@material-ui/core/TableContainer";
import TableHead from "@material-ui/core/TableHead";
import TableRow from "@material-ui/core/TableRow";
import TableSortLabel from "@material-ui/core/TableSortLabel";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";

function createData(name, calories, fat, carbs, protein) {
  return { name, calories, fat, carbs, protein };
}

function descendingComparator(a, b, orderBy) {
  if (b[orderBy] < a[orderBy]) {
    return -1;
  }
  if (b[orderBy] > a[orderBy]) {
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}

function getComparator(order, orderBy) {
  return order === "desc"
    ? (a, b) => descendingComparator(a, b, orderBy)
    : (a, b) => -descendingComparator(a, b, orderBy);
}

function stableSort(array, comparator) {
  const stabilizedThis = array.map((el, index) => [el, index]);
  stabilizedThis.sort((a, b) => {
    const order = comparator(a[0], b[0]);
    if (order !== 0) return order;
    return a[1] - b[1];
  });
  return stabilizedThis.map((el) => el[0]);
}

const headCells = [
  {
    id: "name",
    numeric: false,
    disablePadding: true,
    label: "Dessert (100g serving)",
  },
  { id: "calories", numeric: true, disablePadding: false, label: "Calories" },
  { id: "fat", numeric: true, disablePadding: false, label: "Fat (g)" },
  { id: "carbs", numeric: true, disablePadding: false, label: "Carbs (g)" },
  { id: "protein", numeric: true, disablePadding: false, label: "Protein (g)" },
];

function EnhancedTableHead(props) {
  const { classes, order, orderBy, onRequestSort } = props;
  const createSortHandler = (property) => (event) => {
    onRequestSort(event, property);
  };

  return (
    <TableHead>
      <TableRow>
        {headCells.map((headCell) => (
          <TableCell
            key={headCell.id}
            sortDirection={orderBy === headCell.id ? order : false}
          >
            <TableSortLabel
              active={orderBy === headCell.id}
              direction={orderBy === headCell.id ? order : "asc"}
              onClick={createSortHandler(headCell.id)}
            >
              {headCell.label}
              {orderBy === headCell.id ? (
                <span className={classes.visuallyHidden}>
                  {order === "desc" ? "sorted descending" : "sorted ascending"}
                </span>
              ) : null}
            </TableSortLabel>
          </TableCell>
        ))}
      </TableRow>
    </TableHead>
  );
}

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    width: "100%",
  },
  paper: {
    width: "100%",
    marginBottom: theme.spacing(2),
  },
  table: {
    minWidth: 750,
  },
  visuallyHidden: {
    border: 0,
    clip: "rect(0 0 0 0)",
    height: 1,
    margin: -1,
    overflow: "hidden",
    padding: 0,
    position: "absolute",
    top: 20,
    width: 1,
  },
}));

export default function CollapsibleTable({ data }) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [order, setOrder] = React.useState("asc");
  const [orderBy, setOrderBy] = React.useState("calories");

  const handleRequestSort = (event, property) => {
    const isAsc = orderBy === property && order === "asc";
    setOrder(isAsc ? "desc" : "asc");
    setOrderBy(property);
  };

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Paper className={classes.paper}>
        <TableContainer>
          <Table
            className={classes.table}
            aria-labelledby="tableTitle"
            size={"medium"}
            aria-label="enhanced table"
          >
            <EnhancedTableHead
              classes={classes}
              order={order}
              orderBy={orderBy}
              onRequestSort={handleRequestSort}
              rowCount={data.length}
            />
            <TableBody>
              {stableSort(data, getComparator(order, orderBy)).map(
                (row, index) => {
                  const labelId = `enhanced-table-checkbox-${index}`;

                  return (
                    <TableRow hover>
                      <TableCell
                        component="th"
                        id={labelId}
                        scope="row"
                        padding="none"
                      >
                        {row.category}
                      </TableCell>
                      <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                        {row?.tripStartTimeStr}
                      </TableCell>
                      <TableCell align="center">
                        {row?.drivingTimeMinsStr}
                      </TableCell>
                      <TableCell align="center">
                        {row?.distanceDriven + " " + row?.distanceMetric}
                      </TableCell>
                      <TableCell align="center">{row?.smoothTurning}</TableCell>
                    </TableRow>
                  );
                }
              )}
            </TableBody>
          </Table>
        </TableContainer>
      </Paper>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is the console log generated when I click sort Icon.

[image]

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take a look at tour https://stackoverflow.com/tour to get a better understanding about https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Another good read: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions?. Afterwards, please edit your question to add all the relevant code.